# How can I interpret LiDar data packets coming over UDP?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, lidar

I am using a Velodyne vlp-16 Lidar puck and need to interpret the raw values it broadcasts over UDP.

I have established a socket and I am getting readings but I cannot figure out how to break up and interpret the data I am getting as distances and angles.

---

```
import socket

IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.1.77"
PORT_NO = 2368

IP_ADDRESS_2 = "127.0.0.1"
PORT_NO_2 = 6789

serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind((IP_ADDRESS, PORT_NO))

sendingSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
array = [None]*64

while True:
    array = serverSocket.recv(1248)[0:1248]
    for x in range(42, 48, 1):
        print(x, end ="\n")
    print()
```

---

I see the byte data coming over UDP but I do not understand how to translate that into a distance. I get numbers between 0 and about 600.

[Packet Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UetND.png)

[Velodyne Coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO5Xy.png)

Answer (score 0):

The manual has a some good info on setup

https://velodynelidar.com/lidar/products/manual/63-9113%20HDL-32E%20manual_Rev%20G.pdf

General setup on pg 5

1. Establish communication with the HDL-32E
2. Create a calibration table from the included db.xml data file
3. Parse the packets for rotation, distance and intensity data (suggest using Wireshark)
4. Apply the vertical angle calibration factors to the data
5. Plot or store the data as needed

Also the manual mentions a db.xml for parsing udp to useful metrics

This parser uses that db file

https://github.com/ritzalam/velodyne-lidar-parser